# how to hide the div which is inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to hide a div which is inside a iframe , is there any way to hide a div by its attributes

example: i have a iframe i need to hide the `div id="content"` content in `php.net`

```
<iframe src="http://php.net/" id = 'iframe'>
      <div id="content">...</div>
</iframe>
```

Dont know where i am doing mistake, please help me to resolve this issue

```
function hideIt(){
   document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Your function is correct but it will work only if the document within the iframe is in the same domain as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an issue because of security reason.

Have a look at http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually trying to do this with http://php.net/ ? Because, as Corinne Kubler points out, you cannot do this for security reasons (unless your content was actually hosted on php.net) as it would violate the same-origin policy.

If you open your web browser's debugger / developer tools (try F12 or use the menus), you can check the console and try this - it will probably say "Permission denied" or something (IE9 gives "Access is denied").